# How do I add Shipping cost levels based on 'Order Cost' in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Please excuse me I'm a total noob to PHP and Im building a site and using woocommerce.

I want to add a shipping cost to the cart based on the 'Total Order Cost' like this:

Order Value £0  - £19.99 | Shipping £3.50

Order Value £20.00  - £50.00 | Shipping £4.99

Order Value £50.00 - £100.00 | Shipping £6.99

Order Value £100.00+ | Shipping £0.00

Ive been reading another thread on here and Ive managed to string this code together from other peoples input advice, but I don't know where exactly I'm to add this code in the php. Or if it will work! Ha :/

Can anyone assist me with this please? 
Thanks in advance!

```
class WC_Your_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {
    public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
    global $woocommerce;
                if($carttotal < 20){
                        $cost = 3.50;//3.50;
                    }else if($carttotal > 20 && $carttotal < 50){
                        $cost = 4.99;//4.99;
                    }else if($carttotal > 50 && $carttotal < 100){
                        $cost = 6.99;//4.99;
                }else if($carttotal > 100{
                        $cost = 0;//0;
                    }
                }
$rate = array(
    'id' => $this->id,
    'label' => $this->title,
    'cost' => $cost,
    'calc_tax' => 'per_order'
);
// Register the rate
$this->add_rate( $rate );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code in your theme's functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You should create new file custom_class.php and put your code and include custom_class.php in your theme's functions.php file.

I have suggested to create new file and include in functions.php because functions.php have almost functions but you are using class so create class file and put all custom class code inside. its formal structure.